# Accessing protected member of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, visibility

I have a template class for which I need to access a protected member function of the template parameter, like this:

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    static void bar(T& self){self.foo();}
};
...
Foo f;
Bar<Foo>::bar(f);
```

My problem is getting access to the protected method. I tried putting a `friend class T` into Bar, but that doesn't seem to be allowed in c++ (edit: and wouldn't solve my problem anyways, so it seemd). I tried letting Bar inherit from T (`template<typename T> class Bar: public T` (could have used private inheritance, but the public interface of Bar is not terribly important, since the class itself is internal only)), but that didn't allow for access of `foo()` either. So how do I get access to the `foo()` method?

Edit:
`Foo` should not need to know `Bar<Foo>`, since there are quite a lot `Bar` classes. I can however make other changes to Foo (without changing the public interface of course).

Comment: Is this homework? You should look up what protected means. This will tell you who has access to the method.

Comment: No it's not homework and  this isn't so much about who has access to the method, but how to make it accessible for the class which doesn't. And how would looking up protected help me solve this problem (besides I know in generall wahr it means, I just haven't encountered a situation like this, so throwing inheritance at it seemed like a good starting point)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, this is a "rot in hell" hack. You can abuse the fact that you can form pointers-to-members pointing to protected base members from a derived class.

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

// Helper template to bypass protected access control
// for a member function called foo, taking no parameters
// and returning void.
template<typename T>
struct Unprotect : public T
{
    typedef void (T::*FooPtr)();
    static FooPtr GetFooPtr()
    {
        return &Unprotect::foo;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    static void bar(T& self){(self.*Unprotect<Foo>::GetFooPtr())();}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar<Foo>::bar(f);
}
```

Comment: Hackish as this might be, it should do the job and since those classes are not for external use I can live with a bit ugly code, so thanks.

Comment: This is a lot of fun. There are also ways to circumvent private access: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html :)

Comment: @litb: Nice, I too thought that it wasn't possible to subvert private protection.

Answer (score 2):

You did your friend declaration in the wrong direction. If `Bar` says `Foo` is it's friend, that means `Foo` gets access to `Bar`'s private data. For `Bar` to get access to `Foo`'s private data, `Foo` has to say `Bar` is its friend.

Comment: I thought it worked the other way arround, but then I normally avoid using friend, so anyway. As specified in my edit, putting Bar<Foo> as friend of Foo is not really an option, so while good to know, this doesn't really solve my problem (should have specfied sooner, I know)

Comment: It's either this or nothing. Read the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    static void bar(T& self){self.foo();}
};

class Foo
{
protected:
    void foo() {}
    friend class Bar<Foo>;
};

void main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar<Foo>::bar(f);
}
```

Comment: While that would work it is not really the solution I'm looking for since I have several "Foo" and several "Bar" class (which can each be combined which each other), so putting in a friend class for each combination option is not really a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a protected member a derived class **of `this`**, you can do it with the `using` keyword:

```
class A
{
protected:
  void i_am_protected () {}
};

template <class T>
class B : public T
{
  using T::i_am_protected;

  void call_me ()
  {
    i_am_protected(); // OK.
    this->i_am_protected(); // This compiles without the keyword.
  }
};
```

If you need B to access a protected member of A when an object is passed to B, you need to declare B as a friend of A:

```
class A
{
  template <class T>
  friend
  class B;

protected:
  void i_am_protected () {}
};

template <class T>
class B : public T
{
  void call_me (T& obj)
  {
    obj.i_am_protected(); // OK.
  }
};
```