# C++ Call private / protected function of a common base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, friend

Is there a nice way to call `A::foo()` from `B::bar()` in the following sample?

```
class A {
protected:
  void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void bar(A& a) { // edit: called with &a != this
    a.foo(); // does not work
  }
};
```

I can't think of anything other than declaring `B` to be a friend of `A`, but that could get pretty ugly with some more classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does `B::bar` need to call `A::foo`?  If `A::foo` is protected, that is supposed to mean that only objects of type `A` and any type derived from `A` should be able to call it.  If you really need to call `A::foo` from an unrelated class, perhaps it shouldn't be protected.

Comment: What is the reason for passing an `A` instance to `B` when `B` is a type of `A`?

Comment: @Mihran The 1st sentence is the question.

Comment: I did not intend to use `B::bar` on `*this` but on other instances (actually on other subclasses of A). `A::foo()` is protected for a reason, I'm writing a library here and do not want developers to use it.

Comment: There's no nice way because you want break the normal access protection rules. It is possible to "work around" protected access though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364722/accessing-protected-member-of-template-parameter/3365221#3365221

Comment: Why do you need too? If you have to then you have too and you should make it a friend (don't try and hack around the protection mechanism (with inheritance) try and use the available functionality). Maybe an exact description of what you want to do will help, these hypothetical s only go sofar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a base-class function.

```
class A {
protected:
  void foo() {}
  void do_other_foo(A& ref) {
      ref.foo();
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void bar(A& a) { // edit: called with &a != this
    this->do_other_foo(a);
  }
};
```

Comment: that's working of course. not really nice, but probably the best solution. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you passing object of type A? You could do like this :

```
class B : public A {
public:
  void bar() {
    foo();
  }
};
```

or, like this

```
class B : public A {
public:
  void bar() {
    A::foo();
  }
};
```

Comment: I did not intend to use `B::bar` on `*this` but on other instances (actually on other subclasses of A).

Comment: @lucas Sounds like a design problem. Why is foo() protected?

Comment: See my post above, I do not want classes / functions outside my library to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to giving "protected" like access, allowing calls by *any* derived classes or object.
It uses a protected token type, required to un-lock privileged methods:

```
struct A
{
protected:
    //Zero sized struct which allows only derived classes to call privileged methods
    struct DerivedOnlyAccessToken{};

public:     //public in the normal sense :
    void foo() {}

public:     //For derived types only :
    void privilegedStuff( DerivedOnlyAccessToken aKey );
};

struct B: A
{
    void doPrivelegedStuff( A& a )
    {
        //Can create a token here
        a.privilegedStuff( DerivedOnlyAccessToken() );
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    A a;
    a.foo();
    a.privilegedStuff( A::DerivedOnlyAccessToken() ); // compile error.

    B b;
    b.doPrivelegedStuff( a );

    return 0;
}
```

This is not my idea. I read it some place. Sorry I dont recall who's cunning idea it was.

I expect the compiler can elide the aKey parameter.