# multiple protected inheritance with polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, protected

I have a question about multiple inheritance of protected function and polymorphism.
It's quite hard to describe it so I hope it will be clear enough.

Say I have three classes:

```
class baseClass
{
 protected:
    virtual int function() = 0;
}; 


class derived_A:public baseClass
{
  int function()
    {
      //implementation 1
    };
};


class derived_B:public baseClass
{
   int function()
     {
       //implementation 2
     };
 };


class derived_C:public derived_A, public derived_B
{
  baseClass ** p_arr; //array of pointers of baseClass kind (polymorphism)
  int x=0;

  for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) // array size = many classes like derived_A, derived_B...
  {
     x = p_arr[i]->function(); //I already have function that builds this array
                               //it is not the question so I didn't put it here.
     // process x
   }

};
```

Finally my question is - how can I access that "protected" `function()` from `derived_C` class (inside the for loop)?
I am a bit confused... and will be happy for explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When C++ permits access to `protected` members, it's only to the members of **this** object (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829518/accessing-parents-protected-variables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class)). The code `x = p_arr[i]->function()` tries to call a method in another object, so the compiler complains.

To fix your code, you can make `function` public, or add a `friend` declaration to `baseClass`, like this:

```
class baseClass
{
 public:
    virtual int function() = 0;
};
```

Or

```
class baseClass
{
 protected:
    friend class derived_C;
    virtual int function() = 0;
};
```

However, to retain the `protected` access and not mention the name of the derived class in the base class, you can fix your code by adding a `static` accessor function to the base class:

```
class baseClass
{
 protected:
    virtual int function() = 0;
    static int call_the_function_on_object(baseClass& obj) {return obj.function();}
};
```

Use it (in a derived class) this way:

```
x = call_the_function_on_object(*p_arr[i]);
```

You can also give the accessor function the same name, but then, if your `derived_C` overrides the virtual method, it will hide the accessor function. You can fix that by referring to the base class explicitly:

```
class baseClass
{
 protected:
    virtual int function() = 0;
    static int function(baseClass& obj) {return obj.function();}
}; 

...
class derived_C:public derived_A, public derived_B
{
    ...
        x = baseClass::function(*p_arr[i]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! I tried to begin with your first solution of declaring the function as friend:
at the BaseClass:
friend int derived_c::function();
but I get this error: 'derived_C' : is not a class or namespace name
why do I get this message?

Comment: also, if I add #include BaseClass, it will be circular include and "bad design" as I saw on other posts... or maybe I wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible to declare a friend method in an undeclared class. So just make the whole `derived_C` class a friend. I have added the syntax to do it.

Comment: I made the derived_C a friend of BaseClass. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case your `function()` is private in derived classes. So, from `derived_C` you cannot directly access that function.

However, if you are willing to make it `public/protected`. Then you can use:-

```
derived_C dc;
dc.derived_A::function();
dc.derived_B::function();
```

Comment: `protected` would suffice.

Comment: In the context of this answer, it would. But OP's code is different, so only `public` will help.

Comment: @anatolyg Why do you think that?

Comment: @AlanStokes This is explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27768172/509868); also reproduced [here](http://ideone.com/YmDIbe)