# Is this way to extend a library with virtual protected methods safe?

Tags: c++, protected

An external library that I'm using has the following structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
protected:
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct B : A {
    void f() {printf("B\n");}
};
```

I have now extended this library by

```
struct C : A {
    void f() {printf("C\n");}
};
```

Now I would like a `struct D : A` that uses either `B`'s or `C`'s `f()` depending on information available at runtime. I cannot modify the library and it is not practical to have `C` inherit from `B`, since `B` is much more complicated than `C`. This is what I came up with:

```
struct _A : A {
    // bypass protected
    inline void _f() {f();}
};

struct D : A {
    D(char x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 'B': p = (_A*) new B(); break;
        case 'C': p = (_A*) new C(); break;
        }
    }

    ~D() {delete p;}

    void f() {p->_f();}
    _A* p;
};

int main() {
    D b('B'), c('C');

    b.f();
    c.f();
}
```

I tested it on MacOSX and it works correctly with both g++ and clang++. But is it generally safe? If not, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `B`, `C` and `_A` are unrelated. Trying to treat one as one of the others is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.

You are casting B to _A which can change along the way. The fact that currently _A is identical to A is just a coincidence on which you cannot depend on.

If your goal is to access a protected function, you can use a pImpl approach :

```
struct _Abstract {
     virtual void doF()=0;
}
struct _B : B, _Abstact {
     void doF(){f();};
}
struct _C : C, _Abstract {
     void doF(){f();};
}

struct D {

     D (_C* impl)
     {
          pImpl = impl;
     }
     D (_B* impl)
     {
          pImpl = impl;
     }
     void f() { pImpl->dooF();};

     private:
        _Abstract* pImpl;
}
```

Then you can have

```
D* b = new D(new _B());
D* c = new D(new _C());

b->f();
c->f();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, what you have is not safe. `B` and `C` don't inherit from `_A`, so treating them like such is Undefined Behaviour. It might work, it might crash, it might order pizza online, all depending on the current phase of the Moon. So don't do it.

And I believe you don't have to. The following should work:

```
struct BB : B
{
  using B::f;  // Make it public
};


struct D : A
{
    D(char x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 'B': b.reset(new BB()); break;
        case 'C': c.reset(new C()); break;
        }
    }

    void f()
    {
      if (b) b->f();
      else c->f();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<BB> b;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c;
};
```

The idea is to keep at most one of the pointers non-null (or find another way of determining whether you have a `BB` or a `C` — [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) might be useful too).

---

Please also note that the name `_A` is illegal for user code. Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler and standard library.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelCMS' answer seems to be the best, since the inheritance from `_Abstract` makes my sketchy cast formally correct. Also, as opposed to @Angew's answer, it scales nicely if there are many classes like `B` and `C`. I had to modify it slightly to apply to my example:

```
struct _Abstract {
    virtual void _f() = 0;
    virtual ~_Abstract() {}
};

template <class T>
struct _A : T, _Abstract {
    // bypass protected
    void _f() {T::f();}
};

struct D : A {
    D(char x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 'B': p = new _A<B>(); break;
        case 'C': p = new _A<C>(); break;
        }
    }

    ~D() {delete p;}

    void f() {p->_f();}
    _Abstract* p;
};
```

Obviously, the whole problem would disappear if the library designer had left `f()` public... So please, library designers, leave your methods public! You cannot anticipate all use cases and you are just forcing us to circumvent your protected's (or even private's) by more or less sketchy methods...

**Edit**

In practice, the dual-inheritance solution didn't work so well, since it was leading to a diamond-inheritance problem in my case which greatly complicated things. Inspired by @Charles Bailey's answer to [Accessing protected member of template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364722/accessing-protected-member-of-template-parameter) I came up with this:

```
struct U : A {
    typedef void (A::*f_t)();
    static inline f_t _f() {return &U::f;}
};

struct D : A {
    D(char x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 'B': p = new B(); break;
        case 'C': p = new C(); break;
        }
    }

    ~D() {delete p;}

    void f() {(p->*U::_f())();}
    A* p;
};
```

This directly tackles the problem at its root, namely that a method was set to protected instead of public, while not unnecessarily complicating the inheritance situation. Since this is just a trick to remove the protected attribute via a member function pointer, it should be safe :-)