# Member access of template specialisation in unspecialised template

Tags: c++, templates

The following code fails to compile (using clang):

```
template<int N>
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() : value(N) { }

        void getValue(Foo<1>& foo)
        {
            value = foo.value;
        }

    protected:
        int value;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Foo<1> fooOne = Foo<1>();

    Foo<2> fooTwo = Foo<2>();

    fooTwo.getValue(fooOne);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is `main.cpp:21:15: error: 'value' is a protected member of 'Foo<1>'`. Which is all well and good.

My question is *is there a way to get this to work using friend*? For example the following code produces the same error, but I hoped that it would have worked.

```
template<int N>
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() : value(N) { }

        friend class Foo<1>;

        void getValue(Foo<1>& foo)
        {
            value = foo.value;
        }

    protected:
        int value;
};
```

I can of course be terribly horrible and use the tricks in [Accessing protected member of template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364722/accessing-protected-member-of-template-parameter) or http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm. But I'd rather not resort to hackery of that level for something that I'm probably just being dense about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `friend`-ing the wrong way. It's `Foo<N>` that needs to be a friend of `Foo<1>`, since it needs to access `Foo<1>`'s internals; you are making `Foo<1>` a `friend` of `Foo<N>`. For simplicity, you could just `friend` all of them:

```
template <int N>
class Foo {
    // mass inter-Foo friendship
    template <int > friend class Foo;

    // rest as you had before
};
```

Comment: Ah yes... I have been greeted by my old friend the face palm.

Comment: Any way to do this in a more constrained way? That is to ensure that Foo<N> is only a friend of Foo<1>? If I had my way with the code I'd split the two classes out from each other as they subtly do different things.

Comment: @BenWhale Just rename `Foo<1>` to be like... `Bar`. If they do different things, why have them share a template?

Comment: Long story short: it's legacy code of a complicated nature and the higher ups, quite legitimately, don't want me messing around too much in case I add new bugs. This question is related to a small attempt to increase encapsulation which will help to prevent further abuse of the object Foo<N>.