# How can I shuffle a std::stack in C++?

Tags: c++, stack, c++14, shuffle

I have an STL stack that contains pointers to objects. How can I shuffle the order of the items inside the stack? Can I use the algorithm library, or do I need to write my own algorithm to do it?

I have been able to find details on how to shuffle built-in arrays and STL vectors, but I have been unable to find how to shuffle a STL stack.

```
#include <stack>

stack <Card*> mystack;
// [code to fill stack with pointers is here, but has been omitted as irrelevant]

// function call to shuffle the stack should go here
```

Comment: ...don't use a `stack` if you need to do non-stacky things - like shuffling - with it?

Comment: You'll have to dump your stack into something else (like a `std::vector<Card*>`), shuffle *that* and then dumb that back into your stack. A stack is the wrong container for this. You can only access the top of the stack so you can't shuffle it without also emptying it.

Comment: unfortunately I am required to use a stack as this is for an assignment, so I may have to do as you suggested and dump it into a vector or an array.Thank you for the input @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Small side note: It's very likely based on the name `Card` that there is no good reason to use pointers here instead of plain objects. It's likely going to make everything more complicated for no benefit.

Comment: (There *are* various hacks through which you can get your hands on the `stack`'s underlying container - it's a protected data member named `c` and access control in C++ is not watertight - but it's probably not the point of this exercise.)

Comment: Use e.g. a vector for the shuffling, then insert the data from the vector into your stack.

Comment: Are you sure the assignment requires you to use `std::stack` specifically and not just some kind of stack? In my experience, I consider using `std::stack` at first but then I realise that `std::stack` is too restrictive for my needs so I use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Kerndog73 it definitely requires std::stack.

Answer (score 4):

This shows one of the ways you can bypass access control in C++ and shuffle the underlying container of the `std::stack` directly. Which is almost certainly not the point of your assignment...

```
using stack_c_ptr_t = std::deque<Card*> std::stack<Card*>::*;

constexpr stack_c_ptr_t stack_c_ptr();

template<stack_c_ptr_t p>
struct hack {
    friend constexpr stack_c_ptr_t stack_c_ptr() { return p; }
};

template struct hack<&std::stack<Card*>::c>;

void shuffle_stack_hack(std::stack<Card*>& mystack) {
   auto& c = mystack.*stack_c_ptr();
   std::random_device rd;
   std::shuffle(c.begin(), c.end(), rd); // because I'm too lazy to properly seed a PRNG with rd
}
```

Comment: There's no bug. As with many things in C++, access control is designed to defend against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: Related: [Accessing protected member of template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364722/)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) or [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), the input type must meet the following requirement:

> RandomIt must meet the requirements of [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) and [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

[`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) does not even have an iterator type let alone an iterator type that meets the above requirments.

If you are forced to deal with the task of shuffling the contents of a `std::stack`, you can:

1. Copy the contents to a `std::vector`.
2. Shuffle the contents of the `std::vector`.
3. Copy the contents of the `std::vector` to the stack.

Comment: Don't use `random_shuffle`.

Comment: Can you explain why rather than leaving a cryptic comment that leaves a reader wondering what the issue is?

Comment: @1118321 It was removed and c++17 and no longer exists.